# How do you log the db connection opening and closing in Django?

Tags: python, django

I read that the db connection in Django will be closed after a specified amount of seconds via [CONN_MAX_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-CONN_MAX_AGE). Is it possible for me to add a logging handler to find out when the connection has been closed? Is it also possible to log whether a new connection has been opened because the old connection has already been closed?

I don't think using [django.db.backends logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) will be able to give me that information. I also want to know certain stats for the connection like how long has it been opened? Does anyone know whether this is possible to log via Django?

Comment: You can create a middleware in order to log the connection states as well.